# CRUD repository not returning the Super Class data

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, repository, crud

I have a class which extends some of the basic properties from another class. I am using CRUD repository to communicate with my MySql Database. I am not getting the values for the fields that are defined in the base class.

Ex: I am getting createdBy  and modifiedBy as null.

**Entity Class**

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
class User extends BaseEntity {

 @JsonProperty("id")
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 @Column(name = "id")
 private String id;

 @JsonProperty("firstName")
 @Column(name = "first_name")
 private String firstName;

 @JsonProperty("lastName")
 @Column(name = "last_name")
 private String lastName;

 /**
  * @return the id
  */
 public String getId() {
  return id;
 }

 /**
  * @param id the id to set
  */
 public void setId(String id) {
  this.id = id;
 }

 /**
  * @return the firstName
  */
 public String getFirstName() {
  return firstName;
 }

 /**
  * @param firstName the firstName to set
  */
 public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
 }

 /**
  * @return the lastName
  */
 public String getLastName() {
  return lastName;
 }

 /**
  * @param lastName the lastName to set
  */
 public void setLastName(String lastName) {
  this.lastName = lastName;
 }
}
```

**Base Class**

```
class BaseEntity {

 @JsonProperty("createdBy")
 @Column(name = "created_by")
 public String createdBy;

 @JsonProperty("modifiedBy")
 @Column(name = "modified_by")
 public String modifiedBy;

 /**
  * @return the createdBy
  */
 public String getCreatedBy() {
  return createdBy;
 }

 /**
  * @param createdBy the createdBy to set
  */
 public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
  this.createdBy = createdBy;
 }

 /**
  * @return the modifiedBy
  */
 public String getModifiedBy() {
  return modifiedBy;
 }

 /**
  * @param modifiedBy the modifiedBy to set
  */
 public void setModifiedBy(String modifiedBy) {
  this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
 }
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Transactional
public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository < User, String > {}
```

**Service Implementation Method**

```
public User getUser(String userId) {
    User user = gUnifyUserRepository.findOne(userId); 
    //Here the data for createdBy and modifiedBy is returned as null though i have value in DB
    return response;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date lastModified;
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;
```

use the above code, and let me know

Comment: My question is not about in particular to audit fields. Am not getting the values for subclass fields. In my sample i don't have lastModified and createdAt.